# react-native-datepicker change the input format

Tags: react-native, datepicker

Is there a way to change the modal format on the `react-native-datepicker`? I am not seeing anything in the documentation or questions / issues in the repo.

https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

Everything is working as expected just curious if I could format it with the year scrollable first, then the day, then the month. I am not talking about the place holder which can be formatted with the "format" attribute. I am talking about the modal that allows you to select the date.

```
<DatePickerModal
    ref={datePickerRef}
    date={value}
    mode="date"
    placeholder="Select date"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    maxDate={moment().subtract(18, "years")}
    confirmBtnText="Confirm"
    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
    showIcon={false}
    customStyles={dateInputStyles}
    onDateChange={onDateChange}
  />
```